# Enforcing corporate desktop and short cuts on Ubuntu 12.04 Unity

Tags: unity, settings, default

How can I enforce the same desktop image and pre-created desktop shortcuts for all users on Ubuntu 12.04 Unity and prevent users from changing them please?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I'm aware of is Sabayon.

> Sabayon is a system administration tool to define and deploy desktop
>   profiles for the GNOME desktop environment. It allows you to control
>   such things as panel layouts, menu items, default gconf settings, as
>   well as provide pre-defined defaults for some non-GNOME programs such
>   as Firefox. It also makes use of the lockdown functionality of
>   Pessulus. It does this by providing a "desktop within a window",
>   allowing you to customize your desktop as you see fit, then recording
>   your changes, to be applied to users by the sabayon-apply program at
>   login time.<sup>[Sabayon](https://wiki.gnome.org/Sabayon/)</sup>

For more information, and to download, visit their [Website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Sabayon/).

Comment: Thanks Mitch, it sounds like what I'm looking for.  I downloaded Sabayon, extracted the archive and ran ./configure as the installation instructions suggested.  I get an error message as follows: "checking for headers required to compile python extensions... not found
configure: error: Can't locate python headers". Any suggestions as to how to fix this please?

Comment: Try installing python headers `sudo apt-get install python-pyrex`